# How to automatically pivot data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I am used to work with Excel and trying to learn Python especially Pandas. My goal is to plot a large dataset with Plotly/Dash. My dataset looks very much like the dataset on the Pandas tutorial. I have got more paramters and with 20 locations also more locations.

```
                       date.utc            location parameter  value
2067  2019-05-07 01:00:00+00:00  London Westminster        no   23.0
2068  2019-05-07 01:00:00+00:00  London Westminster       no2   45.0
2069  2019-05-07 01:00:00+00:00  London Westminster      pm25   11.0
1003  2019-05-07 01:00:00+00:00             FR04014       no2   25.0
100   2019-05-07 01:00:00+00:00             BETR801      pm25   12.5
1098  2019-05-07 01:00:00+00:00             BETR801       no2   50.5
1109  2019-05-07 01:00:00+00:00  London Westminster        co    8.0
```

I import the file with pd.read_csv and then manually create a pivot for every location and every parameter with a seperate variable and this is quite a work to do.

Is there a way to automatically pivot this data? I want the locations grouped and a column for every parameter. My goal is to have this data in dash and at the top I want a dropbown with the location and on the right side I want to choose no, no2, pm .... with individual axis labels for each parameter.

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859122/dash-callback-with-dropdown) on stack overflow and trying to adapt it for me but it doesn't work.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/mpk100/CSV?valuePresentation=Value&timeOrder=Ascending&LAND=*&Tid=*', sep=';')
df = df[df['INDHOLD'] != '..']
df['rate'] = df['INDHOLD'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
available_countries = df['LAND'].unique()
df.groupby('LAND')
```

Many thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```py
x = df.pivot(["date.utc", "location"], "parameter", "value")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
parameter                                      co    no   no2  pm25
date.utc                  location                                 
2019-05-07 01:00:00+00:00 BETR801             NaN   NaN  50.5  12.5
                          FR04014             NaN   NaN  25.0   NaN
                          London Westminster  8.0  23.0  45.0  11.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was thinking to complicated. 

Is there also a chance to handle the location in groups to compare the hourly developtment of the value with different locations? In Excel it was quite easy in pover pivot, I just needed the location as the filter and I could compare it.